# Why does it select only one single element with LINQ to XML?

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, linq

I'm treating to recover the binding directives of the machine.config file with LINQ to XML. I have many of them, something like:

```
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Mityc.Sigetel.ComplaintsTeams" publicKeyToken="159574ffe4118e68"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.0.5.65535" newVersion="1.0.5.18135"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Mityc.Sigetel.Ham" publicKeyToken="159574ffe4118e68"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.0.65535" newVersion="5.2.0.21977"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Mityc.Sigetel.Common.Territories" publicKeyToken="159574ffe4118e68"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.2.65535" newVersion="1.1.2.20631"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
```

But, if I write this, I recover only one element (there are lots of them):

```vb
''' <summary>
''' Load the framework machine.config file.
''' </summary>
Public Sub Load()
    Dim machineFile As XDocument = XDocument.Load(_pathToFile)
    Dim iWantMoreElements = machineFile.Descendants("dependentAssembly").ToList()
    'iWantMoreElements.Count = 1
End Sub
```

How can I recover all of them? Thank you very much.

Comment: Your `From dependentAssembly In` is useless.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I changed it in my code. Thanks.

Comment: Should work. I tried it in C#, and got the three entries.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me, but I finally found the reason: the namespace of the assemblyBinding element. I had to specify it in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem was about **namespaces**. The parent element in the XML, *assemblyBinding* has a namespace specified. So, if I want to recover the children of it from the *root* element, I have to write something like this:

```
Public Sub Load()
    Dim machineFile As XDocument = XDocument.Load(_pathToFile)
    Dim ns As XNamespace = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"
    Dim iWantMoreElements = machineFile.Descendants(ns + "dependentAssembly").ToList()
    'iWantMoreElements.Count = 32
End Sub
```

I was recovering only one element because that element had specified a namespace like *xmlns=""*. The rest of them, not.

Thank you very much for your help.